# C# Разрезать текстовый файл по разделителям и сохранить в множество файлов

Tags: c#, словари

Вопрос: Есть 1 текстовый файл, в котором указаны пути файлов. В списке нет разделителей типа ; или каких либо других. В качестве условного разделителя используется определенное имя файла. Пример:
    
    `C:\===01====.txt
    C:\qwerty.txt
    C:\asdfg.txt
    C:\===02===.txt
    C:\zxcvb.txt
    //....так далее`

 Там где встречаются строки формата - C:\===01====.txt - это и есть разделитель. Будущее имя файла получаем из него методом удаления всего лишнего. Т.е. имя файла будет 01.txt

Я понимаю что файл нужно считать стримридером, в цикле while получать значения. И вот тут собственно вопрос: Если использовать Dictionary  - где ключом будет полученное имя файла, например 01.txt, то как потом заполнить значения для параметра Value. Получать последний ключ словаря не есть хорошая идея. И для Dictionary для параметра Value следует использовать просто string с "\n" или лучше массив строк?

В конечном итоге, мне нужен массив, в котором будет ключом имя файла, а в value содержимое между разделителями. Потом это я буду записывать в отдельные файлы.

Извините если вопрос тупой, но нормальной реализации простой задачи я не нашел, а с тем как адекватно заполнить Dictionary (или может имеет смысл что то другое использовать?) я пока не разобрался.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на несколько частей: чтение строк из файла просто в `List<string>`, запись строк в файл и обработку строк. Когда напишите все три программы, то не будет проблемой объединить функционал в одной. Ведь нагуглить (в том числе пользуясь поиском по ruSO) такие вещи куда проще, верно? Навык декомпозиции - это важно в программировании.

Comment: Если будут какие-то конкретные проблемы, которые не получится решить с помощью гугла то приходите сюда с ними и примерами кода, который не работает так, как вы задумываете.

Comment: @free_ze Спасибо. Я все думал как это сделать в одном цикле. Но видимо придется разбить на несколько задач.

Comment: Это не проблема сделать и в одном цикле, но чтобы понять, как это делать, стоит сначала научиться написать простые програмы для каждой задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути, вам надо читать построчно и определять, если это терминальный файл - то создавать новую коллекцию и писать её в словарь. Если это обычный файл = то добавлять его в текущую коллекцию. 
Примерный код (запускать на свой страх и риск)

```
var fname = @"C:\.....";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var current = string.Empty; 
var regex = new Regex(@"C:\\=+[0-9]+=+\.txt");

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fname))
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(line))
    {
        current = line.Replace("=", string.Empty);
        dict.Add(current, new List<string>());
    }
    else
    {
        dict[current].Add(line);
    }
}

// Вывод, что напарсили
foreach (var file in dict.OrderBy(x=>x.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Key);
    foreach (var subfile in file.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{subfile}");
    }
}
```

Вывод на ваших данных будет

```
C:\01.txt
  C:\qwerty.txt
  C:\asdfg.txt
C:\02.txt
  C:\zxcvb.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я примерно так и пытался сделать, но обломался на работе с Dictionary, никак не мог туда адекватно добавить значение. Вот эта строчка  dict.Add(current, new List<string>()); то на чем обламывался, потому что не мог понять что туда вставить если я добавляю только ключ.  Спасибо!!

Comment: @DmStk Пожалуйста

Comment: @DmStk если мой ответ реально поможет решить вашу задачу, отметье его галочкой

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня вышло. Я записываю ключом имя файла, а значением List того, что между разделителями. Примерно так это и пытался сделать сначала и благодаря подсказке  @tym32167 смог понять что и как добавлять. Но возникла проблема с тем, что при выполнении кода, даже при условии что текстовик весит всего 14 Кб, программа на секунду-полторы, во время создания файлов и записи в них, залипает. Мне не кажется это нормальным, поэтому думаю как сделать все менее ресурсозатратным.

```
 Dictionary  <string, List<string>> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> ();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyTextFile.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
        {
            string line;
            string tempkey = "";

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string templine;

                if (line.Contains("=========="))
                {
                    templine = line.Replace("==========", "").Replace(".txt", "").Replace(@"J:\SOMEPATH\", "").Replace("_", "-");
                    templine += "music";
                    tempkey = templine;
                    MyDictionary.Add(templine, new List<string>());
                }

                else
                {
                    if (MyDictionary.ContainsKey(tempkey))
                    {
                       MyDictionary[tempkey].Add(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
        foreach (var FilesName in MyDictionary.Keys)
        {
            var fileName = @"C:\DESTINATIONFOLDER\" + FilesName + ".txt";
            foreach (var value in MyDictionary[FilesName])
            {
                File.AppendAllText(fileName, value, encoding);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Если проблема производительности связана со считыванием файла построчно, то можно считать весь файл в память разом - для этого замените в моем примере File.ReadLines на File.ReadAllLines

Comment: @tym32167 Проблема скорее с записью. Потому что при чтении, все хорошо. Но спасибо, заменю. Поскольку прога еще будет делать всякое, то я конечно еще подумаю как можно максимально все оптимизировать. Спасибо!

Comment: Писать тоже можно разом, а не по строчке - это также увеличит скорость работы.